# Python won't write to file

Tags: python, file, parsing, io, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to write a pretty printed email to a .txt file so i can better view what I want to parse out of it.

Here is this section of my code:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "(FROM 'tiffany@e.tiffany.com')") # search and return uids instead
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

html = raw_email
soup = BS(html)
pretty_email = soup.prettify('utf-8')

f = open("da_email.txt", "w")
f.write(pretty_email)
f.close
```

I am not running into any errors, but I can't get it to write the data to the file.  I know that the data is properly stored in the pretty_email variable because I can print it out in console.

Any thoughts?

MY UPDATED CODE THAT STILL DOESN'T WORK:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "(FROM 'tiffany@e.tiffany.com')") # search and return uids instead
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

html = raw_email
soup = BS(html)
pretty_email = soup.prettify('utf-8')

with open("da_email.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(pretty_email)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to invoke the close method to commit the changes to the file.  Add `()` to the end:

```
f.close()
```

Or even better would be to use [`with`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

```
with open("da_email.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(pretty_email)
```

which automatically closes the file for you

Comment: Just to add... if you don't wish to close the file for whatever reason, you can flush the write-buffer by calling `f.flush()`.

Comment: i also tried your second method to no avail. am i correct in assuming that this will write the file to wherever this script is executing from?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right directory?  It may be putting it in (some weird place)/da_email.txt depending on how your program is invoked.  If it tried to write and couldn't, it would throw an exception.

Comment: To the current working directory, to be more specific. But it will most likely be where you start it from (depends what IDE you're using).

Comment: @user1887261 - Yes.  If you do not specify a full path, Python will look for the file in the same directory as the script (or current working directory if you changed it).  If it finds it, it will write to that.  Otherwise, it will create the file in that directory.

Comment: If you want to check what your `cwd` is run this: `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: so the wd is C:\\users\\Andrew which is what i expected, but the file is still not there and still no error!

Comment: @user1887261 - I'm sorry but I don't understand how it could be failing.  Even if the file doesn't exist, it should create one since you opened it in write mode.

Comment: @iCodez: The working directory is not generally the same directory as the script, except in the case where you run the script from the command line as `python foo.py` (as opposed to, say, double-clicking it, running it from your IDE, running it as `python myscripts/foo.py` from the command line, etc.).

Comment: i know - this is very bizarre. i normally wouldn't have to struggle with this, but i am so perplexed.

Comment: @user1887261: Let's rule out pwd/path problems completely by doing `with open(r"C:\users\Andrew\da_email.txt", "w") as f:` and see what happens.

Comment: i just got it to work by putting the full path that i want to write the file to in the script

Comment: not sure why this worked and what i had before didn't...oh well. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with stopped jobs in the background which had locked the files and there was access to them not possible. (WSL on Windows)

Needed to kill the background jobs (in Task Manager) and then the access was possible.

Comment: @ouroboros1 This is one possible solution when the files are locked by previously runned python scripts.

Comment: @ouroboros1 I disagree. This appears to be a good-faith attempt to answer the question. I don't know whether it's the *correct* answer or not, but that's a matter for voting (not for the very low quality queue).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine: sure, it seems fine now. Note that the answer was only edited *after* my initial review. Improvement being the overall aim of these reviews: all good!

Comment: @ouroboros1 Yes, now I see now, I forgot to check the edit history - the original answer was indeed NAA.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the brackets at the end of `f.close()`.

Comment: This is the same as the 3 year old accepted answer.

Answer (score -5):

I recommend putting double // at each /.

Comment: Op does not use path in the question, their path is in the execution dir

Comment: And, on top of that, doubling forward slashes doesn’t do what you think it does. You have them confused with backward slashes.